# Check equality to a set of values in an array with a specific value and return index

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a following array: `[400, 600, 1000]` - I need to see a changing/dynamic value against this array if it equals to any of the values inside the array and return the index of the value matched.

Tried:

```
arr.every(x => x = dynamicValue );
```

This return boolean

Comment: `arr.every(x => x = dynamicValue );` is setting a value, you need to use the equality operator `arr.every(x => x === dynamicValue );`

Comment: indexOf() will do

Comment: @CodeManiac wouldn't indexOf give me a bool as well?

Comment: @monkeyjs it will give index of match if not than -1. in case you want bool you can use includes

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find index:

```
let yourArray = [400, 600, 1000];
let yourVariable = 600;
let indexElement = yourArray.indexOf(yourVariable);
```

**UPDATE:**

To get indexes of wish elements of array:

```
let yourArray = [400, 600, 1000];    
let yourVariable = 1000;
let yourIndexes = [];
yourArray.forEach((e, i)=>{
        if(e < yourVariable) 
            yourIndexes.push(i);
    });
```

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/1646240/stepup Is there a way I get all indices that are less than 600 here? filter returns updated array with matched values - but how to get the indices - here I need to get [0,1] - when checked value in array<yourVariable.

Comment: @monkeyjs please, see my updated answer.

Comment: works like charm. Thank you so much @StepUp.

Comment: @monkeyjs I've found a bag in my implementation. Now it works properly. See necessary indexes in `yourIndexes` array. Feel free to ask any question. If you found that my reply is helpful, you can mark it as an answer to simplify the future search of other people.